# Where is function location of mass delete orders

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, adminhtml, delete

I am working on my module.I want to know location of function which is call when orders are deleted from admin after select check box and then select Delete action and hit Submit.

Comment: have you added any custom extension for this?

Comment: No i want to know location of file where core function is working for delete orders.

Comment: I want to check login in that function first for deletion of order.

Comment: Magento not provided default functionality for the delete orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento not provided functionality like delete orders

if you want to delete order you want to install some order delete extension

here is some best order delete extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

https://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-delete-orders.html

https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/delete-any-order

or you can do it with codding

here is tutorial

http://inchoo.net/magento/delete-test-orders-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

By default you can't delete orders in Magento. However there are several extensions available that will allow you to delete orders either individually or in bulk such as this one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

Alternatively you can write your own massDeleteAction as outlined here:
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/

Answer (score 0):

In app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php you can remove and change delete action.

`$this->_removeButton('delete');` and remove `deleteConfirm` in this file , I hope this helpfull for you one time open this file. You can also understand

Comment: You should add more details to the answer as one line answers are generally not helpful. In this particular case, it isn't clear what you meant by showing the location of that file.

Comment: please edit your answer instead of posting all in the comments :)